# Simple geometry question involving the circumradius of a triangle.

Tags: triangles

Prove that
$\sin(2A)\overrightarrow{OA}+\sin(2B)\overrightarrow{OB}+\sin(2C)\overrightarrow{OC} =0 $

Where $O$ is the circumradius of the $ABC$ triangle

How to approach this type of problem?

How do we demonstrate that for P ( a point in the triangle ) we get :

$\overrightarrow{PO}=\frac{\sin(2A)\overrightarrow{PA}+\sin(2B)\overrightarrow{PB}+\sin(2C)\overrightarrow{PC}}{\sin(2A)+\sin(2B)+\sin(2C)} =0 $ only if O = P

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your problem. The side should not appear in the sine function. Suppose that it's true for a particular triangle. If I increase the size of the triangle by a factor of $2$, the $OA, OB, OC$ increase by a factor of two as well. Which is fine in the first equation. But the argument of sines wil double, and I assume it might change the equation. The only valid solution would be $O=A=B=C$

Comment: The mistake was that the angles were written in lowercase and I thought those were the sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact [trilinear coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates) of the circumcenter $O$ are $[R\cos A;R\cos B;R\cos C]$, hence the trilinear coordinates are $[\cos A;\cos B;\cos C]$ and the [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) are $[a\cos A; b\cos B; c\cos C]$ or $[\sin(2A);\sin(2B);\sin(2C)]$. It follows that
$$\vec{O}=\frac{\sin(2A)\vec{A}+\sin(2B)\vec{B}+\sin(2C)\vec{C}}{\sin(2A)+\sin(2B)+\sin(2C)}$$
and if the reference system is centered at $O$
$$0=\frac{\sin(2A)\vec{OA}+\sin(2B)\vec{OB}+\sin(2C)\vec{OC}}{\sin(2A)+\sin(2B)+\sin(2C)}.$$